# emacs cedit c++ code completion fails

Tags: c++, emacs, autocomplete, cedit

I am new to emacs and i was try to use cedit for code completion.
 I use a simple setting based on http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html

The .emacs looks like this:

```
;; cedit
(semantic-mode 1)
(require 'semantic/ia)
(require 'semantic/bovine/gcc)
;;(require 'semantic/bovine/clang)
;;(semantic-clang-active)

(setq-mode-local c-mode semanticdb-find-default-throttle
                 '(project unloaded system recursive))

;;(semantic-idle-summary-mode )
;; if you want to enable support for gnu global
(semanticdb-enable-gnu-global-databases 'c-mode)
(semanticdb-enable-gnu-global-databases 'c++-mode)
;;(semantic-reset-system-include 'c-mode)
;;(semantic-reset-system-include 'c++-mode)
(defun my-c-mode-cedet-hook ()
 (local-set-key "." 'semantic-complete-self-insert)
 (local-set-key ">" 'semantic-complete-self-insert))
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my-c-mode-cedet-hook)
(add-hook 'c++-mode-common-hook 'my-c-mode-cedet-hook)

(defun my-c-mode-cedet-hook ()
  (add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-gtags)
  (add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-semantic)
  (add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-semantic-raw))
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my-c-mode-cedet-hook)


(global-ede-mode t)
```

After i test with this simple c++ file:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  string s; 

  map<int,int>a;

}
```

I found it can complete keyword like include or header file.While when i try to complete the method of s,it fails.And when i use the command `semantic-ia-complete-symbol`
It just reports `Cannot find types for string s`

Can anybody tells me why it cannot work?
And thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Just update to latest Emacs.
There, your example works with zero config, i.e.

```
emacs -Q test.cc
```

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `semantic-mode`, `semantic-ia-complete-symbol`.

Comment: I tried this but it won't work.I am using emacs 24.3.1. If i define a class in this file and it can complete the methods successfully.